# Why does it say argument is invalid

Tags: replacement

I have a huge expression where I want to replace the variables $a,b,z$ in terms of other variables.

This is the original expression:

```
ExpandAll[ (Gamma[a-b+1]/Gamma[1-b])E^(z+p) Gamma[1 - a] ((-(Gamma[b - 1]/Pi)) ((-z^(1 - b)) Sin[Pi a] + (-z)^(1 - b) Sin[Pi (b - a)]) Series[Hypergeometric1F1[1 - a, 2 - b, -z],{z,0,3}] + (1/Gamma[1 + a - b]) Series[HypergeometricU[-a + b, b, -z],{z,0,3}] )]
```

This is my attempt.

```
rules = {a :> -r/D, b:> -1/g,  z:> (D*t)/g , p :> -r*t};

ExpandAll[ (Gamma[a-b+1]/Gamma[1-b])E^(z+p) Gamma[1 - a] ((-(Gamma[b - 1]/Pi)) ((-z^(1 - b)) Sin[Pi a] + (-z)^(1 - b) Sin[Pi (b - a)]) Series[Hypergeometric1F1[1 - a, 2 - b, -z],{z,0,3}] + (1/Gamma[1 + a - b]) Series[HypergeometricU[-a + b, b, -z],{z,0,3}] )]//.rules
```

For some reason, there is an error displayed that first argument is invalid.

Any thoughts on why this error appears?

[image]

Comment: Don't use `D` it's a reserved name in Mathematica.

Comment: Also, you may need to apply `Normal[]` before the `/. rules` substitution to get rid of the warning message.

Comment: I tried changing $D$ to some other alphabet like $X/Y/H$ etc. Still the problem persists.

Comment: As ulvi said, also apply `Normal` to convert the `SeriesData` objects generated by `Series` into polynomials: `Normal[ExpandAll[(Gamma[a - b + 1]/Gamma[1 - b]) E^(z + p) Gamma[
     1 - a] ((-(Gamma[b - 1]/Pi)) ((-z^(1 - b)) Sin[
           Pi a] + (-z)^(1 - b) Sin[Pi (b - a)]) Series[
        Hypergeometric1F1[1 - a, 2 - b, -z], {z, 0, 3}] + (1/
         Gamma[1 + a - b]) Series[
        HypergeometricU[-a + b, b, -z], {z, 0, 3}])]] //. rules`

Comment: Thank you, it is resolved with the help of comments from @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: and with the help of @ulvi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one of the replacement rules there is the following expression `z:> (D*t)/g` (there's actually no need to use `:>` as there doesn't seem to be anything present that requires delayed evaluation on the *rhs* of the rule; using `->` will suffice). Now there are two problems with this rule:

1. `D` is a reserved symbol used by *Mathematica* (try `D[x^2,x]`); this in itself is not detrimental, as it is *possible* to evaluate expressions like *eg* `(D-2)^2` but in the present case, that is not a feature of the language that is required; like the comments indicate, it could be less error prone (or *future-proof*) to replace `D` with another symbol, preferably *not* used as a system function.
2. I will abstract from the provided code for ease of exposition: evaluating an expression like  `Series[f[a,x],{x,b,3}]/.x->d t/g` produces a message `SeriesData::sdatv` with a text reading "*First argument $\frac{d t}{g}$ is not a valid variable*".

   Let's break it down:

   - first of all, what is the `Head` `SeriesData`? Afterall, we just evaluated a `Series` expression. It [turns out](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) that

     > "`SeriesData` is the head of the basic expressions generated by `Series`"
   - why then is it not possible for `SeriesData` to have a *first argument* like `d t/g`? Well, that's how it [works](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/SeriesData/sdatv.html). Notice how

     > "*Most* expressions **other** than numbers, sums, *products*, powers, inequalities, and logical expressions **can** be used as variables."

   In the present case, using the replacement rule `x->d t/g` replaces `x` in the resulting `SeriesData[x,...]` expression  with `dt/g` which is in fact a product involving a `Power` expression (evaluate `FullForm[d t/g]`).

In order to resolve the problem we need to supply `SeriesData` with an expression as a first argument that is acceptable or we can turn the `SeriesData` into a `Normal` expression and then `ReplaceAll` the rules.

A way for doing the former is `Normal[Series[f[a,x],{x,b,3}]/.x->head[d t/g]]/.head->Identity` while the later can be achieved with `Normal[Series[f[a,x],{x,b,3}]]/.x->d t/g`. Lastly applying `ExpandAll` to either of those expression will produce the expected result.